# Magento skipping Sub-Theme to default

Tags: theme, magento-1.6, parent-child-theme

I can't seem to find anything at all on the internet related to my problem which makes me think I've done something wrong along the way which has eluded me for days now.

I have a theme I downloaded called 'Ultimo' and I want to make changes to the header.phtml file without changing the core file, so obviously I would make a sub-theme/child-theme.

Inside the Ultimo 'package' it has a default theme called 'default'

To make a sub-theme I need to make a folder alongside 'default' called 'custom_theme' and then enable it within the admin panel, See below.
[image]

I delete the cache after any changes I make.
There is nothing in system > design that could override anything.

If I rename the folder 'default' to something else ONLY THEN will magento load in the desired sub-theme.

So obviously magento is skipping the sub-theme I created and going straight to default.

Please can anybody help me as I'm not sure what is making Magento behave like this.

(I made a test copy of my site from before I added the new theme and was able to add the theme, create a sub-theme and enable it no problem)

Comment: Have you tried putting `custom_theme` in the other settings as well (Layout, Skin, Templates, etc.)?

Comment: Yes I've tried that also, pretty much every variation

Comment: And, just to be completely clear, when you say Magento is skipping your sub-theme and going straight to default, are you referring to Ultimo's default theme (ultimo/default), or Magento's own default theme (default/default or base/default)?

Comment: It is skipping to Ultimo's default theme (ultimo/default).
(I know this because if I edit the .phtml files within this directory then I can see changes)

Comment: Hm, that's odd. What you're doing should work fine. I even double checked the source to be sure - it should check `ultimo/custom_theme`, then `ultimo/default`, then `base/default`. Does the Ultimo theme come with a module that perhaps overrides Magento's default theme configuration logic somehow? I see some Ultimo settings on the left side of your screenshot.

Comment: Very odd! The funny thing is, it was actually working two days ago for a short while after I rebooted my pc.
So it makes me think that it may have something to do with my wamp server.
And I don't think it comes with a module that does that.
There is something very small that I'm overlooking that is causing this but I just don't know what it is.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue yet?